# I can't compare sql_variant field with IS NULL operator

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, sql-variant

I mean I can't query null values when column type `sql_variant`

For example `docsdate` table look like this:

```
ValID DocID     Value  <--sql variant column)

 1. 488 146      30.10.2007
 2. 740 190      31.03.2008
 3. 570 161      31.10.2008 
 4. 242 103      NULL
 5. 248 104      NULL
```

When query like `select * from docsdate where value is null` 
no rows returned

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see this behavior - your query works just fine for me ...

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Are you sure your `NULL` values are actually proper NULLs and not strings containing the text `NULL`? Do they show up with a yellow background in SSMS?

```
create table #docsdate 
(
ValID int,
DocID int,
value sql_variant
)

INSERT INTO #docsdate
SELECT 488,146,'30.10.2007' UNION ALL
SELECT 740,190,'31.03.2008' UNION ALL
SELECT 570,161,'31.10.2008' UNION ALL 
SELECT 242,103,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 248,104,NULL

SELECT * FROM #docsdate
WHERE value IS NULL

DROP TABLE #docsdate
```

Comment: martin thats exactly what you point , value is string null; silly me :)